# jQuery Plugin AJAX Local XML

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml

I am trying to write a jQuery plugin and read through some XML, but I don't seem to be getting any return values. The xml seem to be coming back ok if I just console.log using debugging tool, but it doesn't seem to be parsing. I tried different parsing method, but doesn't seem to be outputting.

JavaScript Code

```
;(function ($) {

    /**
     * Plugin Definition
     */
    $.fn.extend({

        feedr: function (option) {

            var result;
            var $this = this;

            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'feedr.xml',
                dataType: 'xml'
            })
            .done(function (xml) {
                var xmlDocument = $.parseXML(xml);
                var $xml = $(xmlDocument);
                var $type = $xml.find('type');

                return $this.html($type.text());
            });

        }

    });

}(jQuery));
```

XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<feedr>
    <feed>
        <type>rdf</type>
        <uri>ABC</uri>
    </feed>
    <feed>
        <type>rdf</type>
        <uri>ABC</uri>
    </feed>
    <feed>
        <type>rss</type>
        <uri>DEF</uri>
    </feed>
</feedr>
```

HTML File

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="feedr/js/jquery-feedr.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('.feedr').feedr();
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="feedr" class="feedr" data-xml="feedr"></div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Do you have a fiddle / plunker / etc that demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix change your done() to this:

```
.done(function (xml) {
    var $xml = $(xml);
    var $type = $xml.find('type');

    return $this.html($type.text());
});
```

The reason is that the ajax call specifies that the content coming back is XML so jQuery pre-parses it and hands it to done as an XML document, not a string.

So, you are trying to turn a document into a document, the action fails and returns null.

Here's a fiddle that may help you - http://jsfiddle.net/XjDfp/